# Find first non zero numbers in an array (zeroes can be anywhere)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Suppose we have an array: `x = [10,0,30,40]`.  I would like to extract the first non zero element and store it in a different variable, say `y`. In this example, `y = 10`.  We can also have many zeros, `x = [0,0,30,40]`, which should give `y = 30` as the extracted value.

I tried a Python snippet like this:

```
i = 0
while x[i] != 0:
  y = arr[i]
  if x[i] == 0:
     break
```

This only works if the array is `[10,0,30,40]`.  It does not work if I have `0,20,30,40`.  The loop would stop before that. What is an efficient way to implement this? I try not to use any special Numpy functions, just generic common loops because I might need to port it to other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
x = [10,0,30,40]
for var in x:
    if var != 0:
        y = var
        break
```

Comment: You don't need an extra variable. Even after `break`, `var` will still hold on to the last value of the loop. You can then use `for-else` to see if the loop finished (ie no non-zero found)

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to get all the non-zero values, then provided there are some non-zero values extract the first one.

```
x = [10,0,30,40]

lst = [v for v in x if v != 0]

if lst:
  y = lst[0]
  print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of new to this but i think this should work:

```
x = [0, 12, 24, 32, 0, 11]
y = []
for num in x:
     if num != 0:
         y.append(num)
         break
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you don't increment `i` so it's stuck on the first element. So what you could do to keep the code portable is:

```
while x[i] != 0:
  y = x[i]
  if x[i] == 0:
     break
  i+=1
```

This code is still not clean, because if there is no `0` in your array then you will get an `IndexError` as soon as you reach the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next function:

```
x = [10,0,30,40]
next(n for n in x if n) # 10

x = [0,0,30,40]
next(n for n in x if n) # 30
```

if you need to support the absence of zero in the list, you can use the second parameter of the next() function:

```
x = [0,0,0,0]
next((n for n in x if n),0) # 0
```